# How do I write this sentence in indirect speech?

Tags: reported-speech

Write the following line in indirect speech:

> The boy said,"I have had my lunch today"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boy said that he had had his lunch that day.

Comment: Had had? That sounds weird.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had